# How to vary thickness of line on the plot?

Tags: plotting

How to plot the function f(x) so that one part be a thicker line than another depending on the value x? (Curve is efficient frontier - portfolio optimization)

Comment: All kinds of ways to skin that cat, a quick-n-dirty way is something like this: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> Plot[Sin[x], {x, 3, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01]][[1]]]`

Comment: @MichaelE2: That is a sweet answer from you in that link.

Answer (score 7):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 300] /.  Line[x_] :> Line /@ Partition[x, 2, 1] /. 
                                     Line[x_] :> {Thickness[.02 Abs@x[[1, 2]]], Line[x]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You have not only skinned that cat, you've made a fur-covered Bentley out of it. +1

Comment: @rasher Slightly better now